# Facebook's in-app-browser returns the error "net::ERR_FAILED", but no other browser

Tags: wordpress, facebook, inappbrowser

The Facebook in-app-browser returns the error "net::ERR_FAILED". What could be the reason for this?

The website was made a long time ago for me and my brother and it has worked fine until recently. Suddenly we couldn't open in Facebook in-app-browser anymore. I've tried to look for error but none are printed (neither in PHP nor JS console). The website works great on all other browsers. I've even tried using Ghostlab (hosting on local PC and visit the website via this URL on the in-app-browser), and by doing that it works.

I except the page to be loaded. Right now nothing is loaded and I'm left without any logs.

Comment: Have you found any solution? It seems that recently we started to experience the same.

Comment: same problem here :( complaints started about a week ago

Comment: We're also experiencing problems, but our Service Worker is passing out a "You are Offline" page instead. We found that clearing the browser cache helps, but we're unable to force the SW to update from our end:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56730703/facebook-in-appbrowser-opens-offline-file-from-serviceworker

Unsure if related to your problem, but for some reason FB's browser seems to think users are offline for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved after the update that came a few days later. But I never figured out the issue. Let's hope it doesn't happen again.