# Facebook In AppBrowser opens Offline file from serviceworker

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

Clicking on links in Facebook Mobile Browser opens offline file specified by serviceworker.

We have implemented a serviceworker on our websites which in case the website is offline, loads an html page from cache.

I have tried to uninstall the serviceworker, but the in-app browser still loads the offline page

Our serviceworker looks a follows

```
 //This is the "Offline page" service worker

//Install stage sets up the offline page in the cache and opens a new cache
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  var offlinePage = new Request('/CMSContent/Pages/Offline.html');
 event.waitUntil(
   fetch(offlinePage).then(function(response) {
     return caches.open('sw-offline').then(function(cache) {
      return cache.put(offlinePage, response);
    });
  }));
});

//If any fetch fails, it will show the offline page.
//Maybe this should be limited to HTML documents?
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
  fetch(event.request).catch(function (error) {

  return caches.open('sw-offline').then(function(cache) {
      return cache.match('/CMSContent/Pages/Offline.html');
  });
}
  ));
});

//This is a event that can be fired from your page to tell the SW to update the offline page
self.addEventListener('refreshOffline', function(response) {
    return caches.open('sw-offline').then(function(cache) {
   return cache.put(offlinePage, response);
 });
});
```

When clicking on links in Facebook App, it loads the offline page.

Comment: I have replaced the implementation of the serviceworker with the code below, but Facebook in-app browser still caches the old version

            navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function (registrations) {
                for (let registration of registrations) {
                    registration.unregister()
                } 
           })

Comment: Currently we're experiencing the same problem... We tried updating Workbox, which fixed the issue, but were left with users havign the old servcie worker in the browser.

We also tried deregistering, registering a 'different' one suing a query string and using `skipWaiting();` to no avail.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56681774/update-service-worker-in-facebook-browser